# Find N max difference between two consecutive number present in file using unix

Tags: shell, unix

Integer numbers are stored in file, i need to find Max and N Max difference between two consecutive number present in file ( one integer number on each row/line)
e.g.

```
 12
 15
 50
 80
```

Max diff : 35 ( 50 -15 ) and say N=2 so 1st max 35 and 2nd max : 30

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a programming question? This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump your homework and expect someone else to do it for you.

Comment: difficulty is not in logic but m not very well aware of unix commands which can be useful in this scenario

Comment: m reading file n iterating line by line.. i thought if it can be done using awk.. but it requires to remember the earlier no

Comment: @MarcB i would request you not misuse ur score to decrease the score of others without knowing Q or spirit behind Q.. I respect ur knowledgeable but seems u haven't answered many question related to unix scripts.. Thanks :)

Comment: the actual context of my problem is i m solving performance issue. hv converted date from log file into integer ..n find out the difference between two consecutive calls just wanted to know max time taken by which call , and log file is in gbs

Comment: The point is, we are happy to help you solve your programming problems, but the process starts with YOUR CODE. Post your attempt to solve this yourself. In addition to your expected results, include your actual results, or the error produced by your attempt.

Comment: i think u hv been too impatient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR>1{ diff = $0 - prev
      for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (diff > maxdiff[i])
        { # sort new max. diff.
          for (j = N; --j > i; ) if (j-1 in maxdiff) maxdiff[j] = maxdiff[j-1]
          maxdiff[j] = diff
          break
        }
    }
    { prev = $0 }
END { for (i in maxdiff) print maxdiff[i] }
```

- e. g., if the script is named `nmaxdiff.awk` and the numbers are stored in the file `numbers`, enter

```
nmaxdiff.awk N=2 numbers
```